# Django LDAP Active Directory

Tags: django, active-directory, ldap

I'd like to use the existing Active Directory system for authentication of users, but there is a problem.

This works:

```
ldapsearch -D  "LOGIN@dom.comp.local" -x -w PASSWORD -b "OU=users,OU=otdel,DC=dom,DC=comp,DC=local" -h x.x.x.x
```

Where should I enter the username to connect to the AD?

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ???
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,ou=otdel,dc=dom,dc=comp,dc=local", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(cn=%(user)s)")
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Which Python package are you using for LDAP, and which for Django LDAP?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Python 3 exclusively these days, and the only package I've been able to get working with Active Directory is django-python3-ldap. While configured for OpenLDAP by default, it is a cinch to configure it for Active Directory, and even documented:

https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

Give it a look, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ldapsearch` string, the `-D` argument in the `binddn`.  So, assuming `LOGIN@dom.comp.local` works, you should be able to set `AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN` to that same value.